# How to get a value of a key in session?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm attempting to dig directly from the Cookie request header to a value I've previously stored in the Play session via

```
Http.Context.current().session().put("my-fancy-key", "some-interesting-value");
```

I have ONLY access to the play.mvc.Http.Request from which I'm able to get to the play.mvc.Http.Cookie ... but from there I stumble.

This snippet doesn't work... Hints?

NOTE: I'm totally open to using objects that aren't in the Play framework.  I see Netty has cookie r/w functions and am looking into those ... perhaps something directly in the javax?

```
String playSessionCookieName = Configuration.root().getString("session.cookieName", "PLAY_SESSION");

Http.Cookie playSessionCookie = r.cookie(playSessionCookieName);

if (playSessionCookie != null) {
   // FIXME: What to do here to get my value?

   Logger.debug("Found the cookie! Serialized value: " + playSessionCookie.value());
   try {
      ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(playSessionCookie.value().getBytes()));
      Http.Session session = (Http.Session) objIn.readObject();

      // Here's the goal
      Logger.debug("Found my value: " + session.get("my-fancy-key"));

   } catch (Exception e) {
      Logger.warn("Couldn't deserialize the value.", e);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why You don't use simple `session(key)` to get session value, but if You need to get session values from session cookie You can use something like that (play 2.0).

```
String cookieVal = request().cookies().get("PLAY_SESSION").value();
cookieVal = cookieVal.substring(cookieVal.indexOf("-")+1);
for(String a: cookieVal.split("%00")) {
    String[] k = a.split("%3A");
    // k[0] - session key; k[1] - session value
    Logger.info(k[0] + " = " + k[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was trying to avoid doing string parsing (hoping for something baked into an API) but it is working well.

Comment: With regard to "...don't know why you don't use simple session(key)...", the answer is: "Because you haven't read the question clearly or any of the other comments on the question."

Answer (score 0):

Cookie has a method value(). I dont know if it does what you want but I would start there.

Comment: In the code sample I posed, I am pulling the value from the cookie (look for: playSessionCookie.value()).  The issue is that the play session cookie contains multiple values ... my assumption (in the code snippet I've posted) is that those values are a serialized map subclass: Http.Session.  If I'm right then the way in which I'm deserializing them is incorrect. If I'm wrong, then I've barked up the wrong tree.

Comment: ah sorry, didn't notice that. However, all examples I find just get the value from the session like this: String value = session("key");

Comment: Right! Once I have my hands on the session (or the map it represents), I'll be good to go.  My fundamental problem is that I'm starting with only the cookie value (just the string representing the play session object ... not the actual object itself).  My question is: how do I convert/deserialize/unpack that string into something I can work with?

Comment: Hmm, since you say you only have access to the Http.Request then I can't really help. I would try posting a question in the play usergroup, they are usually pretty fast with answers.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to iterate over the session stored in the result instead of the cookie, if you have access to the result:

```
Session resultSession = play.test.Helpers.session(result);

for (Entry<String, String> entry : resultSession.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("key:" + entry.getKey() + " value:" + entry.getValue());
}
```